# Import Exception DtdProcessing

Tags: python, .net

I am getting the following error:

> Cannot Import Name DtdProcessing

On this line:

```
from System.Xml import (DtdProcessing, ValidationType, XmlNodeType, XmlReader, XmlReaderSettings)
```

What could be causing this? Is there a possibility that I don't have the right version of .net installed?

Comment: works fine for me, does any import from .NET work for you? If yes, then look at this QA for troubleshooting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27725122

Comment: I think I fixed it by installing the correct version of .NET. I do not have this problem anymore.