# Python for .Net Error: ImportError: No module named

Tags: python, .net, dll, assemblies, python.net

We are using Python for .Net to call .NET API built using C# from Python script.
We are getting ImportError: No module named - error when an import is done as follows.

Python script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r"C:\myfolderA\myfolderB")
print sys.path
import clr
clr.FindAssembly(r"AA.BB.CC")
clr.AddReference(r"AA.BB.CC")
from AA.BB.CC.Api.DDInterface import DDClient
```

On the above line I am getting following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\myfolderA\myfolderB\testAPI.py", line 7, in <module>
    from AA.BB.CC.Api.DDInterface import DDClient
ImportError: No module named AA.BB.CC.Api.DDInterface
```

There is no other information available to exactly identify the issue.
Dlls from same project built 15 days back works fine.
This project may have gone through few changes in between.

How to exactly identify this issue?

Could this be a dependency issue? 
I tried  JustDecompile to compare old dlls and new ones, but couldn't find anything unusual.

Your help is deeply appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: You might find the answer in this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/63728744/12821529

Answer (score 2):

With help from python forum I was able to use Microsoft's Fuslogvw.exe (Assembly Binding Log Viewer) and figure out the dependent dll causing the error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to my original answer:

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/pythondotnet/2014-December/001626.html

I recommend using Assembly Binding Log Viewer (fuslogvw.exe) for
corresponding .NET framework to see the log files of loading assemblies.

Set Log Location as Custom and in Settings point to your assemblies folder.
The log should show the sequence of DLLs being loaded and any errors.

This worked for me, see here:

[Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469929/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependencies)

[Can't locate fuslogvw.exe on my machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674279/cant-locate-fuslogvw-exe-on-my-machine)